# Meaning of score in Microsoft Cognitive Service's Entity Linking API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying out the Entity linking API, and there's a **score** field that returns that I'm not sure how to interpret.

Google returns a salience score (how important the entity is in the sentence), but this score seems to behave differently.
I'm guessing it's some sort of confidence, but it's just an educated guess.
In the following example the "New York Knicks" get a score of 0.971.

```
{
    "entities":[{
        "matches":[{
            "text":"The Knicks",
            "entries":[{
                "offset":0
            }]
        }],
        "name":"New York Knicks",
        "wikipediaId":"New York Knicks",
        "score":0.971
    }]
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a developer from the Entity Linking Cognitive Service team.

Yes, the score is confidence score given by our algorithm.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  I removed the email link from your answer; the answers here should be self-contained and public.  If you want to publish your team's email address, feel free to add it to your profile.